# Is it possible to get the root HTML tag, not just body node?

Tags: javascript, dom

In both of the following examples, `speechTextString` ends up including text from the entire document, including text outside of the BODY tag.

Example 1:

```
r = document.body;
speechTextString = r.innerText;
```

Example 2:

```
r = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY").item(0);
speechTextString = r.innerText;
```

Is it possible to get the root HTML tag, not just the body element?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Clarify

Comment: You should provide a testable example. Check if your HTML is correctly formed.

Comment: Is the markup valid?

Comment: please edit question and explain what you want to achieve...

Answer (score 1):

> text outside of the BODY tag

Assuming you aren't talking about the content of the `<head>` element:

You can't have text outside the `<body>` element. HTML does not allow it. The browser performs error recovery and moves it inside the `<body>` element when it parsing the (invalid) HTML into a DOM.

If you want to process a document with that error in it, then you will need to fetch the raw source code (e.g. with `XMLHttpRequest`) and then write a custom parser for it.

Comment: @Kaiido — Comments are comment nodes, not text nodes.